# HP 6120X Blade switch QoS

Tags: switch, network, qos, hp-procurve

I just got access of blade center and i was looking at configuration of switch which is following.

I can see switch has already `QoS` configured, I am not very expert in QoS so trying to understand what exactly its configured?

If i want to remove QoS what are the commands to do that on HP switch, I am familiar with Cisco but HP is new beast for me.

```
swt-blade-1-a(config)# sh run

Running configuration:

; XXXXXXX Configuration Editor; Created on release #Z.14.44

hostname "swt-blade-1-a"
mac-age-time 864000
qos dscp-map 111000 priority 7
qos dscp-map 110000 priority 6
qos dscp-map 101000 priority 5
qos dscp-map 100000 priority 4
qos dscp-map 011000 priority 3
qos dscp-map 010000 priority 2
qos dscp-map 001000 priority 1
qos dscp-map 000000 priority 0
interface 23
   disable
   lacp Active
exit
interface 24
   disable
   lacp Active
exit
interface 1
   name "infra-01"
   unknown-vlans Disable
exit
interface 2
   name "infra-02"
   unknown-vlans Disable
exit
interface 3
   name "infra-03"
   unknown-vlans Disable
exit
interface 4
   name "compute-01"
   unknown-vlans Disable
exit
interface 5
   name "Blade_Servers"
   unknown-vlans Disable
exit
interface 6
   name "Blade_Servers"
   unknown-vlans Disable
exit
interface 7
   name "Blade_Servers"
   unknown-vlans Disable
exit
interface 8
   name "Blade_Servers"
   unknown-vlans Disable
exit
interface 9
   name "Blade_Servers"
   unknown-vlans Disable
exit
interface 10
   name "Blade_Servers"
   unknown-vlans Disable
exit
interface 11
   name "Blade_Servers"
   unknown-vlans Disable
exit
interface 12
   name "Blade_Servers"
   unknown-vlans Disable
exit
interface 13
   name "Blade_Servers"
   unknown-vlans Disable
exit
interface 14
   name "Blade_Servers"
   unknown-vlans Disable
exit
interface 15
   name "Blade_Servers"
   unknown-vlans Disable
exit
interface 16
   name "Blade_Servers"
   unknown-vlans Disable
exit
interface 17
   name "Uplink to cusqui001cn503 e1/4"
exit
interface 18
   name "Uplink to cusqui001cn504 e1/4"
exit
interface 19
   name "uplink"
exit
trunk 18-19 Trk1 LACP
vlan 1
   name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
   untagged 17,20-24,Trk1
   ip address dhcp-bootp
   no untagged 1-16
   exit
vlan 30
   name "mgmt"
   tagged 1-6,Trk1
   no ip address
   exit
qos queue-config 2-queues
qos traffic-template "egressdt"
   map-traffic-group 1 egress-discard-threshold low
   exit
tacacs-server timeout 10
no telnet-server
interface 1
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   no flow-control
   exit
interface 2
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   no flow-control
   exit
interface 3
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   no flow-control
   exit
interface 4
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   no flow-control
   exit
interface 5
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   no flow-control
   exit
interface 6
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   no flow-control
   exit
interface 7
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   no flow-control
   exit
interface 8
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   no flow-control
   exit
interface 9
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   no flow-control
   exit
interface 10
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   no flow-control
   exit
interface 11
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   no flow-control
   exit
interface 12
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   no flow-control
   exit
interface 13
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   no flow-control
   exit
interface 14
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   no flow-control
   exit
interface 15
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   no flow-control
   exit
interface 16
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   no flow-control
   exit
interface 17
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   exit
interface 18
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   exit
interface 19
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   exit
interface 20
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   exit
interface 21
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   exit
interface 22
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   exit
interface 23
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   exit
interface 24
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   exit
```

## UPDATE

In following command output, what exactly its saying, My Plan is to use this blade center for VMWare do you think following config will create any issue in my VMWare traffic? I have little knowledge of QoS so trying to understand impact.

```
swt-blade-1-a# show qos traffic-template egressdt

  TRAFFIC-TEMPLATE:   egressdt
  Status          :   Active

Queue                        Egress Discard
Number    Priorities         Threshold         Name
------    --------------     --------------    --------------------
1         0,1,2,3            Low               best-effort-tcg
2         4,5,6,7            High              control-tcg
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the QoS settings usually involves the statement with a `no` prepended, similar to Cisco devices.

```
qos dscp-map 111000 priority 7
qos dscp-map 110000 priority 6
qos dscp-map 101000 priority 5
qos dscp-map 100000 priority 4
qos dscp-map 011000 priority 3
qos dscp-map 010000 priority 2
qos dscp-map 001000 priority 1
qos dscp-map 000000 priority 0
```

These lines map IP ToS diffserve codepoints to the switch's (802.1p) priorities. Note that other codepoints may already have a default priority. You can check the current table with `show qos dscp-map`.

```
qos queue-config 2-queues
```

Configures the switch to use 2 queues (4 is default, 8 is also possible).

```
qos traffic-template "egressdt"
   map-traffic-group 1 egress-discard-threshold low
   exit
```

Creates a template with low priority for queue 1.

```
interface 1
   policy traffic-template "egressdt"
   ...
   exit
...
```

Applies the template to the desired interfaces.

You can find more details in the *HP ProCurve Series 6120 Blade Switches Advanced Traffic Management Guide* which apparently can't be linked here.

Comment: I have tired `no policy traffic-template "egressdt"` but its not letting me do that, i have tired on `no qos traffic-template "egressdt"` same error its saying it has been in used. I will get you more details once i close to computer

Comment: You cannot delete a template that's in use. You need to remove the template assignment from each interface first, then you can delete the unused template.

Comment: I am not seeing any option to delete template assigned to each interface... see this link i am inside interface-12 and `no ?` not seeing any option to delete. i have tired `no qos` also but nothing changed. https://pastebin.com/ri4n4qmA

Comment: `no interface all policy traffic-template` doesn't work? A template can only be applied to to all ports. This is surely true for removing it as well but I can't see that in the manual. It's possible that a template *needs* to be applied at all times, so you'd create and apply another one.

Comment: `no interface all ?` has following command https://pastebin.com/PWDi4Cf3

Comment: HPE blade switches are somewhat a class of their own - does `no interface all qos ?` lead anywhere? I guess a traffic template is mandatory and you need to replace it with another. It's not in the manual though and I can't test it.

Comment: ++ These switches are piece of crap, no standardization no documentation nothing, I did enough google before coming here. so `?` after `qos` is nothing but `<cr>` I tried that too but nothing change in configuration all looks same in `show run`

Comment: I have updated my question with more info, Do you think i should just leave this setting in place?

Comment: QoS prioritizes some traffic over other traffic - low priority frames get dropped (only) when high priority frames require more bandwidth. As long as the settings are not the opposite of what you need they won't hurt.

Comment: My all traffic is now TCP VMware traffic.. hope it treat it fair